# How do I use conditionals in Angular Expressions with ngDisable?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a DOM button which is disabled when there is no user selected (it's set to false on load) However, I also need to disable this button when an array is empty. For example I have an array of groups, when all groups have been added, I'd like to disable the add button.

```
        <div>
            <label for="entityAvailable">Available Groups</label>
            <select id="entityAvailable" multiple   
                ng-model="selectedAvailableGroups" 
                ng-options="g.name for g in availableGroups | orderBy:'name'">
            </select>
        </div>
        <div id="moveButtons" >
            <button type="button" ng-disabled="!selectedUser || availableGroups == []" ng-click="addUserToGroup()">Add User</button>
            <button type="button" ng-disabled="!selectedUser" ng-click="removeUserFromGroup()">Remove</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="entityAssigned">Assigned Groups</label>
            <select id="entityAssigned" multiple
                ng-model="selectedAssignedGroups" 
                ng-options="g.name for g in assignedGroups | orderBy:'name'">                       
            </select>
        </div>
```

Comment: trying adding brackets around your expression (!selectedUser || availableGroups.length == 0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
ng-disabled="!selectedUser || availableGroups.length == 0"
```

Comment: Worked brilliantly. Thank you.

Comment: what if I needed to make sure it was also disabled if selectedAvailableGroups was empty? I tried doing the same thing but it didn't work.   ng-disabled="!selectedUser || availableGroups.length == 0 || selectedAvailableGroups.length == 0"

Comment: Make sure initially you declared `$scope.selectedAvailableGroups=[]` in your controller otherwise it will be `undefined` until you select any item from your `drop-down` and expression will not execute successfully.